Fingerprint Scanner Not Working on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
I’m having trouble getting my fingerprint scanner to work on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS. I’ve tried various solutions from online resources, but nothing seems to help.
Here’s what I’ve done so far:
Verified that my fingerprint scanner is compatible with Linux.
Updated my system using  **sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade.**
Installed the necessary packages with **sudo apt install fprintd libfprint-2-2.**
Checked if the device is recognized using **lsusb.**
Attempted to register my fingerprint using **fprintd-enroll**.
Reviewed system logs for any related errors with j**[ournalctl -xe | grep fprint.][1]**

Despite these efforts, I’m still facing issues. If anyone has suggestions or solutions, I would greatly appreciate your help!
Thanks in advance!

Do you have any information on hardware model? lspci or lsusb output might be useful
